# ajaxStart not running properly without "alert"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code for trying to put a loader whenever the ajax is still going on. My issue is that if I put the alert, I get what I need. But if I remove the alert, it does not show the "Loading..." .
Javascript:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $('#loading').html("Loading...");
   console.log("hii");
   alert("gg");
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Maybe, I am doing something wrong somewhere but I cannot figure out why whenever I put alert, it shows me the loading page and disappears when I remove the alert.

Any ideas/solution?

Here is example ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: xyz,
    data: dataObj,
    type: request_type,
    async: async_status,
    datType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data){
        DEBUG && console.log("[OK] .", data);

        // Show error messages from server if they exist
        if (data.status == "failure"){
            if (data.code == "104"){
                alert("Your session has expired. Please login again.");
                logout();
            }
        }
        // Check the status is correct
        else {
            tutorialInfo_data = data;
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        DEBUG && console.log("[FAIL] Request failed.");
        failed = true;

        // If request failed, display message
        alert("Sorry, something went wrong.\n\nPlease try again later.");

    },
    complete: function(){
        hideModal();
        busy=false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you hiding it when the request ends?  Maybe the request is too fast for you to see it, and you only see it with the alert because it pauses execution.

Comment: Really? My request is actually so slow that I need to show a loader...I tried doing that too but it didn't show any different results. But you seem to have a valid point. My page freezes without alert and I have to wait for ajax request to end

Comment: Is your Ajax request, by accident, a synchronous request (Jax ;))